# How do I write a name pronounced like "Eye.Sun"?

Tags: pronunciation, names

I'm not sure whether here is the appropriate place for posting my question. Please pardon me if it's not.

My wife and I have chosen a name for our to-be-born daughter which is pronounced like "eye.sun" /aI.san/.
In our language, Turkish, "eye" means the "Moon" and "sun" means the "like" or "similar to". So, this name in the whole means "as beautiful as the Moon" or "like the Moon".
My question form you native or experienced English speakers is which of the following choices has the same pronunciation as in our own language, "eye.sun":

Eyesun, Aysan, Aysun, Isun, Isan, ...

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Turkish uses the Latin alphabet. You write the name in English exactly the same you write it in Turkish. How did you figure out how to write "Bahram" in English?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aysun_%28given_name%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really two different issues here:

1. What spelling is required so that strangers reading the name for the first time correctly guess the pronunciation
2. What's the best spelling for my daughter's name?

For #1, I can only say good luck. Unless you're going with a "standard" name like Sally or John, someone will always mangle it. It's the way of the world. But your daughter will quickly learn to graciously correct them and people are used to this. That said, I like everything you've listed but "Eyesun", which makes my mind go off on weird tangents.

For #2, you have the right to spell and pronounce a name however you like. (Anyone remember "the artist formerly known as Prince"?) I could choose to say my name was pronounced "Jay-EE-sha" and spelled "Q". So pick the spelling you like best. Everyone else will get used to it! :)